# automate iseries navigator generate sql command

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I occasionally use iseries navigators "generate sql" to convert out DDS objects into sql code. Is there a way to automate this? or perhaps a green screen equivalent command? what I'm really after is a way to translate a keyed logical file into a set of sql indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the Generate Data Definition Language (QSQGNDDL) API...

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/apis/qsqgnddl.htm

There's at least two published utilities that use this API.
http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/ibmi/developer/general/Generating-DDL-Source-Using-a-CL-Command/
http://www.itjungle.com/mgo/mgo060502-story01.html

Comment: Thank you for your post. I have seen the QSQGNDDL but I'm not sure how to use it. I need to write RPG code to make this work? the "green screen" is not my area of expertise.

Comment: I included two links to already written tools..you'd just need to compile the source provided.  There should be instructions to do so in the downloads.