# Describe is not working in IBM DB2

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am running an query in IBM DB2 as;

```
DESCRIBE TABLE Schema.Table
```

But I am getting an error as

**DESCRIBE TABLE Schema.Table Error 42601:Token Table was not valid. Valid tokens: :. SQLCODE=-104**

I search a lot but can't find out the reason and as I am very new in IBM DB2 so can't figure out the matter. Is it a permission related issue?

I don't have command prompt access.

Comment: Is this a mainframe DB2 (AS400?)? Afaik DESCRIBE only works on UDB...

Comment: I am not sure. If it is not mainframe DB2 then how to get metadata of a table? And how to know if it is mainframe DB2?

Comment: Using `SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS`?

Comment: Now the error for the query 
SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS is **Error 42704:SYSCOLUMNS in SYSIBM type *FILE not found. SQLCODE=-204**

Comment: Sorry, don't know, better wait for some DB2 pros :-)

Comment: There is a lot of bad information here. Describe works fine on DB2 for i. There are three main flavors of DB2, DB2 for zOS, DB2 for i, and DB2 LUW. They are mostly the same, but there are some platform specific differences. You know which one you are using because of the OS it is running on. If it is running on a mainframe, System z with zOS, then it is DB2 for zOS. If it is running on Power/Pure System with IBM i, it is DB2 for i. Otherwise it is DB2 LUW (Linux/Unix/Windows). BTW, AS400/IBM i is not a mainframe, it is a midrange.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855217/automate-iseries-navigator-generate-sql-command   try using the navigator to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be using DB2 on IBM i (formerly known as AS/400), where [catalog views are in the QSYS2 schema](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcatalogtbls.htm).

In recent versions there are also their equivalents: [SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcatsqlcolumns.htm) and [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcatalog.htm).

Comment: @jmarkmurphy you're right, I removed that comment. DESCRIBE behaves differently across various DB2 platforms.

Answer (score 3):

If you are simply trying to get catalog information for a table or view, the system catalog will work just fine, as noted in another answer by mustaccio. But if you want to embed a `DESCRIBE TABLE` in your RPG or COBOL program, that will work as well. One reason you might want to do this is if you have a dynamic number of columns, or you don't know the table name at compile time. You can use an sql descriptor built by describing a table or cursor to receive the output of a `FETCH` statement in your program. You will need an `SQL Descriptor` or an `SQLDA` to receive the description of the table. It would look something like this:

```
dcl-s tableName     Varchar(128);

exec sql allocate sql descriptor 'D1' with max 20;

tableName = 'MYTABLE';
exec sql
  describe table :tableName
    using sql descriptor 'D1';
```

This will retrieve information about the table into the specified descriptor. In this case `D1`. The descriptor name can be a host variable. This example allocates a `local` descriptor for 20 items. If your table has more than 20 columns, you can request a larger descriptor in the `ALLOCATE DESCRIPTOR` statement. If you will be spreading your sql that uses a given descriptor across multiple modules, you will need to use a global descriptor by replacing `'D1'` with `global 'D1'`. You can also use an `SQLDA`, but I find that those can be more difficult to work with.

To get information out of the descriptor you would use `GET DESCRIPTOR`. It would be beyond the scope of this site to go into all the details of what you can get out of the descriptor, but as an example you could get the column name of the first column of `MYTABLE` like this:

```
dcl-s columnName     Varchar(128) Inz('');

exec sql
  get sql descriptor 'D1'
    value 1 :columnName = name;
```

Don't forget to deallocate the descriptor when you are through with it.

```
exec sql deallocate sql descriptor 'D1';
```

You can find more information on `DESCRIBE TABLE` here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzdescrtb.htm. The knowledge center also has information about `ALLOCATE DESCRIPTOR`, `DEALLOCATE DESCRIPTOR`, and `GET DESCRIPTOR`.